# When i'm trying to create microsoft text driver(.txt , .csv) pointing to some specified .csv file,it don't show the file in Select directory?

Tags: odbc

Actually my intension is talking with non-conventional database like ms=excel,txt files. When i'm trying to create microsoft text driver in data source pointing to some .csv file and also trying to some file in my drives.. in that select Directory file is not visible to pointing it is in hidden mode What is the problem.

[image: this is image]

Answer (score 1):

You must point to the directory in ODBC first, then set the options for the defined column header format.  The ODBC connection will recognize all text files in the directory, and follow the header formats for the columns you must specify